# sort by 2 datefields together

Tags: mysql, datetime

Table:

```
id | date_in             | date_out            |
1  | 2016-01-01 12:00:00 | 2016-01-03 12:00:00 |
2  | 2016-01-01 12:00:00 | 2016-01-02 12:00:00 |
```

I need a query that will return result like this:

```
id | alias
1  | 2016-01-01 12:00:00
2  | 2016-01-01 12:00:00
2  | 2016-01-02 12:00:00
1  | 2016-01-03 12:00:00
```

Comment: give an example, what you want

Answer (score 5):

I would assume something along the lines of a `union` would suffice, since there is no context I can only assume this is what you're looking for?

```
SELECT t.id, t.date_in AS alias FROM test t
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.id, t2.date_out AS alias FROM test t2
ORDER BY alias ASC;
```

Would give you a result like the following:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | alias               |
+----+---------------------+
|  2 | 2016-01-01 12:00:00 |
|  1 | 2016-01-01 12:00:00 |
|  2 | 2016-01-02 12:00:00 |
|  1 | 2016-01-03 12:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Union ALL. Ofcourse! This works just fine for me.

Thanks Ash

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following**

```
SELECT
```

CONCAT(date_in, date_out) as Alias
   FROM table_name;

Comment: How does this answer the question?  [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Comment: The person asking the question said they'd like two columns to displayed as one?

Comment: OP asked for 2 columns over 2 rows to be displayed in 1 column and 4 rows.

Comment: I'm sure you could do a join statement within the same table?

Comment: Sure you could.  See ash's answer for a good example of what to do here.

Comment: Just FYI so you can learn, [here are the results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9435b/1) of your answer.  SQLFiddle is a very useful site for testing out queries like these.

Answer (score 0):

Using a UNION ALL query like Ash suggested answers this question.